# when login the page in url getting username encrypted parameters when remove username parameter need to get logout page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I had developed login page,when login the page in url getting username encrypted parameters.while remove the username parameters in url and refresh the page need to get logout the page?

Comment: it is not clear from your question what you are looking for. can you please post any screenshot or rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

when remove the uname parameter in url and refresh the page need to get logout that user and redirect to home page. how? anybody helpme

Comment: logout from SFDC ?

Comment: Yes,Need to logout from SFDC and redirect to login page...

Comment: you can do that using javascript.

window.location.href='/secur/logout.jsp';

Comment: I am using visualforce pages for login and Home page and I need logout only particular home page and redirect to login page.no need to logout from sfdc.